# ES6 / ES9 group array of objects by multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array of Orders and I need to group them according to the carrierCode:

```
const orders = [
    {
    "depo": "Berlin",
    "boxes": 1,
    "isCOD": true,
    "CODAmount": 45.33,
    "carrierCode": "ups",
    "sid": "DCAC298A627DF2D1980D23F67F05E8E4",
    },
    {
    "depo": "Leipzig",
    "boxes": 2,
    "isCOD": false,
    "CODAmount": 0,
    "carrierCode": "tnt",
    "sid": "8BF93B9159742250CA7F73304808E316",
    },
    {
    "depo": "Leipzig",
    "boxes": 2,
    "isCOD": true,
    "CODAmount": 124.00,
    "carrierCode": "dhl",
    "sid": "0DC1A9BCFA6C5834361AFABBD857CEDD",
    },
    {
    "depo": "Leipzig",
    "boxes": 3,
    "isCOD": true,
    "CODAmount": 415.33,
    "carrierCode": "tnt",
    "sid": "8BF93B9159742250CA7F73304808E316",
    },
    {
    "depo": "Berlin",
    "boxes": 1,
    "isCOD": false,
    "CODAmount": 0,
    "carrierCode": "tnt",
    "sid": "0DC1A9BCFA6C5834361AFABBD857CEDD",
    }
];
```

so far I did this:

```
var groups = orders.reduce((p, c) => {
    var code = c.carrierCode;
    if (!p.hasOwnProperty(code)) {
    p[code] = 0;
    }
    p[code]++;
    return p;
}, {});

console.log(groups);

var countsExtended = Object.keys(groups).map(k => {
    return {code: k, orderscount: groups[k]}; });
  
console.log(countsExtended);
```

that returns

```
{ ups: 1, tnt: 3, dhl: 1 }
```

and

```
[ 
    { code: 'ups', orderscount: 1 },
    { code: 'tnt', orderscount: 3 },
    { code: 'dhl', orderscount: 1 }
]
```

but now I need to group also by depo and 'import' some other values from orders like boxes count, and total COD Amount: practically, and I should get something like this

```
[ 
    { code: 'ups', orderscount: 1, depo:'Berlin', boxes: 1, CODAmount: 45.33},
    { code: 'tnt', orderscount: 1, depo:'Berlin', boxes: 1, CODAmount: 0.00},
    { code: 'tnt', orderscount: 2, depo:'Leipzig', boxes: 5, CODAmount: 415.33},
    { code: 'dhl', orderscount: 1, depo:'Leipzig', boxes: 2, CODAmount: 124.00}
]
```

how can I get this with ES6/ES10?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to leverage just that first `reduce()` function, along with a spread operator to get what you need.

```js
const orders = [{ depo: 'Berlin', boxes: 1, isCOD: true, CODAmount: 45.33, carrierCode: 'ups', sid: 'DCAC298A627DF2D1980D23F67F05E8E4', }, { depo: 'Leipzig', boxes: 2, isCOD: false, CODAmount: 0, carrierCode: 'tnt', sid: '8BF93B9159742250CA7F73304808E316', }, { depo: 'Leipzig', boxes: 2, isCOD: true, CODAmount: 124.0, carrierCode: 'dhl', sid: '0DC1A9BCFA6C5834361AFABBD857CEDD', }, { depo: 'Leipzig', boxes: 3, isCOD: true, CODAmount: 415.33, carrierCode: 'tnt', sid: '8BF93B9159742250CA7F73304808E316', }, { depo: 'Berlin', boxes: 1, isCOD: false, CODAmount: 0, carrierCode: 'tnt', sid: '0DC1A9BCFA6C5834361AFABBD857CEDD', },];

const groups = orders.reduce((p, c) => {
  delete c.sid;
  delete c.isCOD;
  let index = p.findIndex(pi => pi.carrierCode == c.carrierCode && pi.depo == c.depo);
  if (index > -1) {
    p[index].ordercounts++;
    p[index].CODAmount+=+c.CODAmount;
    p[index].boxes+=+c.boxes;
  }
  else p.push({ ...c, ordercounts: 1});
  return p;
}, []);

console.log(groups);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I did not thought to use findIndex, but I would have not found such solution.
I selected this solution because it returns me an array that I can directly pass to `datatable`, although, probably,  other solutions return a more formal correctly solution

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything extra, you can simply capture all the properties that you want in the final objects within your `reduce()`.

Here isolating properties using [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and simplifying the logic a little with [logical nullish assignment (??=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment)

```js
const orders = [{ depo: 'Berlin', boxes: 1, isCOD: true, CODAmount: 45.33, carrierCode: 'ups', sid: 'DCAC298A627DF2D1980D23F67F05E8E4', }, { depo: 'Leipzig', boxes: 2, isCOD: false, CODAmount: 0, carrierCode: 'tnt', sid: '8BF93B9159742250CA7F73304808E316', }, { depo: 'Leipzig', boxes: 2, isCOD: true, CODAmount: 124.0, carrierCode: 'dhl', sid: '0DC1A9BCFA6C5834361AFABBD857CEDD', }, { depo: 'Leipzig', boxes: 3, isCOD: true, CODAmount: 415.33, carrierCode: 'tnt', sid: '8BF93B9159742250CA7F73304808E316', }, { depo: 'Berlin', boxes: 1, isCOD: false, CODAmount: 0, carrierCode: 'tnt', sid: '0DC1A9BCFA6C5834361AFABBD857CEDD', },];

const groups = Object.values(
  orders.reduce((p, { carrierCode: code, depo, boxes, CODAmount }) => {
    p[code] ??= { code, orderscount: 0, depo: {} };
    
    p[code]['depo'][depo] ??= { depo, boxes: 0, CODAmount: 0 };
    p[code]['depo'][depo].boxes += boxes;
    p[code]['depo'][depo].CODAmount += CODAmount;

    p[code].orderscount += 1;

    return p;
  }, {})
).map(({ depo, ...rest }) => ({ ...rest, depo: Object.values(depo) }));

console.log(Object.values(groups));
```

To create a flat array as in the accepted answer you can simply use the same logic but with a composite key made of `depo` and `carrierCode`.

```js
const orders = [{ depo: 'Berlin', boxes: 1, isCOD: true, CODAmount: 45.33, carrierCode: 'ups', sid: 'DCAC298A627DF2D1980D23F67F05E8E4', }, { depo: 'Leipzig', boxes: 2, isCOD: false, CODAmount: 0, carrierCode: 'tnt', sid: '8BF93B9159742250CA7F73304808E316', }, { depo: 'Leipzig', boxes: 2, isCOD: true, CODAmount: 124.0, carrierCode: 'dhl', sid: '0DC1A9BCFA6C5834361AFABBD857CEDD', }, { depo: 'Leipzig', boxes: 3, isCOD: true, CODAmount: 415.33, carrierCode: 'tnt', sid: '8BF93B9159742250CA7F73304808E316', }, { depo: 'Berlin', boxes: 1, isCOD: false, CODAmount: 0, carrierCode: 'tnt', sid: '0DC1A9BCFA6C5834361AFABBD857CEDD', },];

const groups = Object.values(
  orders.reduce((p, { carrierCode: code, depo, boxes, CODAmount }) => {
    const key = `${code}_${depo}`;
    p[key] ??= { code, depo, orderscount: 0, boxes: 0, CODAmount: 0 };

    p[key].orderscount += 1;
    p[key].boxes += boxes;
    p[key].CODAmount += CODAmount;

    return p;
  }, {})
);

console.log(Object.values(groups));
```

Comment: Cool - I haven't seen reduce used like that before. Thx

Comment: I'm not sure how you want to handle multiple `CODAmount` or `boxes` values ... you can quite easily sum them up within the reduce, or accumulate multiples in an array.

Answer (score 0):

I put the result in a bit different structure

```
const result = {};
orders.forEach(({ carrierCode, depo, boxes, CODAmount }) => {

  if (!result[carrierCode]) {
    result[carrierCode] = {};
  }

  if (!result[carrierCode][depo]) {
    result[carrierCode][depo] = { boxes, CODAmount, orderscount: 1 };

  } else {
    result[carrierCode][depo].boxes += boxes;
    result[carrierCode][depo].CODAmount += CODAmount;
    result[carrierCode][depo].orderscount++;
  }
});
```

Result:

```
{
  "ups": {
    "Berlin": {
      "boxes": 1,
      "CODAmount": 45.33,
      "orderscount": 1
    }
  },
  "tnt": {
    "Leipzig": {
      "boxes": 5,
      "CODAmount": 415.33,
      "orderscount": 2
    },
    "Berlin": {
      "boxes": 1,
      "CODAmount": 0,
      "orderscount": 1
    }
  },
  "dhl": {
    "Leipzig": {
      "boxes": 2,
      "CODAmount": 124,
      "orderscount": 1
    }
  }
}
```